# How to get list item value to use in CAML query of SPServices function

Tags: spservices, caml, query

I'm using SPFilterDropdown in a NewForm for a drop-down list which will be huge. I'm using the cascaded dropdown function (SPCascadeDropdowns) to reduce the size but I'd also like to filter the list further by using a value from another column.

The trouble is that the [example supplied](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFilterDropdown) comes with a hard-coded value in the CAML query.  I'd like to use the value selected by the user from a drop-down column in the same NewForm.

```
$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({
      relationshipList: "Countries",
      relationshipListColumn: "Title",
      columnName: "Country",
      CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Active' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>",
      completefunc: null,
      debug: false
```

So I know what value will have FieldRef, it's just how to reference the value from the drop-down that will be used in the Value tag?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code before you use the `SPFilterDropdown` method to find out what the value in the dropdown is. You can use JQuery to get the value of the dropdown and store it in a variable. Then use that variable in the CAML query.

Comment: So, I think I need to use the GetListItems function?  If that is the case then can I use it in this screen for a record that hasn't been stored yet? I'm thinking that I'd have to use something like  <br/>    'var SR_var = ($(this).attr("ows_Title")):'   <br/>But then how would this variable (SR_var) be used in the value tag of SPfilterDropdown?

Comment: Aaah used up the five minutes trying to format!!